# Django: access and update a variable on which to filter during a Django model query?

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I'm hoping to build a Django query to my model that lets my filter change as the query progresses.

I have a model `Activity` that I'm querying for. Each object has a `postal_code` field and I'm querying for multiple zip codes stored in an array `postal_codes_to_query` across a date range. I'd like to ensure that I get an even spread of objects across each of the zip codes. My database has millions of Activities, so when I query with a limit, I only receive `activities` that match zip codes early on in `postal_codes_to_query`. My current query is below:

```
Activity.objects.filter(postal_code__in=postal_codes_to_query).filter(start_time_local__gte=startTime).filter(start_time_local__lte=endTime).order_by('start_time_local')[:10000]
```

If I'm searching for say 20 zip codes, Ideally I'd like to receive 10000 `activities`, with 500 `activities` for each zip code that I queried on.

Is this possible in Django? If not, is there some custom SQL I could write to achieve this? I'm using a Heroku Postgres database in case that matters.

Comment: Forgot to mention, an initial idea was for there to be some sort of variable that could be updated after each object in a zipcode was found and to stop querying that zip once the limit was reached, but I can't figure out how to achieve that effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in a single query, either in Django nor (as far as I know) in SQL.

The best bet is simply to iterate through the list of zips, querying for max 500 in each one:

```
activities_by_zip = {}
for code in postal_codes_to_query:
    activities = Activity.objects.filter(postal_code=code).filter(
        start_time_local__gte=startTime).filter(
        start_time_local__lte=endTime).order_by('start_time_local')[:500]
    activities_by_zip[code] = activities
```

Of course, this is one query per zip, but I think that's the best you're going to do.

Comment: Yeah we tried that, but ufortunately it was really slow. Is it possible to use threading somehow to run the queries at the same time?